# Appending two lists with multiple dicts Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have five dictionaries `dic1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5`. I'm trying to append `dict-keys` to two lists `list1, list2`.

```
dict1 = {"brand": "Ford",
         "model": "Mustang",
         "year": 1964}

dict2 = {"brand": "Acura",
         "model": "Honda",
         "year": 1984}

dict3 = {"brand": "BMW",
         "model": "BMW",
         "year": 1974}

dict4 = {"brand": "Bentley",
         "model": "Volkswagen",
         "year": 1976}

dict5 = {"brand": "Cadillac",
         "model": "GM",
         "year": 1983}
```

**Output**

```
list1 = ['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974, 'Bentley', 'Volkswagen', 1976]
list2 = ['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974, 'Cadillac', 'GM', 1983]
```

The first three dictionaries are to be appended for both the lists and fourth dictionary `dict4` to the `list1` and fifth `dict5` to the list2.

So far I did in this approach,

```
def appendListsFromDict():
    #create Empty List
    list1, list2 = [], []

    #Create blank lists and append lists from each of the dictionaries
    #Appending for list1
    for key in dict1:
        list1.append(dict1[key])

    for key in dict2:
        list1.append(dict2[key])

    for key in dict3:
        list1.append(dict3[key])

    # dict4
    for key in dict4:
        list1.append(dict4[key])   



    #Appending for list2
    for key in dict1:
        list2.append(dict1[key])

    for key in dict2:
        list2.append(dict2[key])

    for key in dict3:
        list2.append(dict3[key])

    # dict5
    for key in dict5:
        list2.append(dict5[key])   

    return list1, list2
```

I'm looking for an efficient and better approach to do this. Any suggestions or references would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list.extend` for the task

```
dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

list1, list2 = [], []
for d in dicts:
    list1.extend(d.values())
    list2.extend(d.values())

list1.extend(dict4.values())
list2.extend(dict5.values())

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Prints:

```
['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974, 'Bentley', 'Volkswagen', 1976]
['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974, 'Cadillac', 'GM', 1983]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list1=list(dict1.values())+list(dict2.values())+list(dict3.values())+list(dict4.values())

list2=list(dict1.values())+list(dict2.values())+list(dict3.values())+list(dict5.values())

>>> print(list1)
['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974, 'Bentley', 'Volkswagen', 1976]
>>> print(list2)
['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974, 'Cadillac', 'GM', 1983]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain

tuple_sum1 = (dict1, dict2, dict3)
x = lambda lis: list(chain(*lis))

list_1 = []

for dic in tuple_sum1:
    list_1.append([v for k, v in dic.items()])

main_list = x(list_1)

list_1 = main_list + list(dict4.values())
list_2 = main_list + list(dict5.values())

print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

Prints:

```
['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974,  'Bentley', 'Volkswagen', 1976]
['Ford', 'Mustang', 1964, 'Acura', 'Honda', 1984, 'BMW', 'BMW', 1974,'Cadillac', 'GM', 1983]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function using a list comprehension to construct the list from the values of all the input dictionaries:

```
def listify(*dicts):
    return [v for d in dicts for v in d.values()]

list1 = listify(dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4)
list2 = listify(dict1, dict2, dict3, dict5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a specific reason to use dictionaries for this, I'd personally use a class, and storing the entries within a list. Here's an example:

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, _brand, _model, _year):
        self.brand = _brand
        self.model = _model
        self.year = _year

carList = []
#Create and store entries
carList.append(Car("Ford", "Mustang", 1994))
carList.append(Car("Acura", "Honda", 1984))
carList.append(Car("BMW", "BMW", 1974))

#Access properties of first two cars
for i in range(2):
    print(carList[i].brand,end=" ")
    print(carList[i].model,end=" ")
    print(carList[i].year)
```

**Output**

```
Ford Mustang 1994
Acura Honda 1984
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [ v for d in (dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4) for v in d.values() ]
list2 = [ v for d in (dict1,dict2,dict3,dict5) for v in d.values() ]
```